# Prevent closing Toast when closing Modal in BootstrapVue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I would like to prevent closing Toast when closing Modal in BootstrapVue.

Scenario:

1. Open the Modal and Toast on the page
2. Close the modal
3. then Modal and Toast closed at the same time

> **Question: how to keep Toast stays**

```
    created() {
       this.$bvModal.show('modal-form-id')
       const errorToaster = {
          title: 'Success',
          toaster: 'b-toaster-top-center',
          variant: 'success'
        }
       this.$bvToast.toast('Success', errorToaster)
    },
    methods: {
       closeModal() {
         this.$bvModal.hide('modal-form-id')
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add $root.

```
this.$root.$bvToast.toast("Success", errorToaster);
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Can you explain a bit more why adding $root solves the problem?

Answer (score 3):

In you `errorToaster` add this `no-auto-hide: true`.

Example:

```js
const errorToaster = {
    title: 'Success',
    toaster: 'b-toaster-top-center',
    variant: 'success',
    'no-auto-hide': true,
}
```

Comment: I try with this:
const errorToaster = {
      title: 'Success',
      toaster: 'b-toaster-top-center',
      variant: 'success',
      'no-auto-hide': true
    }
But it still closed with Modal

Answer (score 2):

Toast has `auto-hide-delay` property - the number of milliseconds before the toast auto dismisses itself, so it closes with no connection to modal closing.

add  to your code:

```
const errorToaster = {
      title: 'Success',
      toaster: 'b-toaster-top-center',
      variant: 'success',
      autoHideDelay: // default is 5000,
      noAutoHide: true // in order to stay it open forever
 }
```

Comment: I try with this:
const errorToaster = {
      title: 'Success',
      toaster: 'b-toaster-top-center',
      variant: 'success',
      autoHideDelay: 1000000
    }

But it still closed with Modal

Comment: Add this property:  `noAutoHide: true`

Comment: @CHHUMSina did `noAutoHide: true` help you?

Comment: it's still the same issue.  const errorToaster = {
      title: 'Success',
      toaster: 'b-toaster-top-center',
      variant: 'success',
      autoHideDelay: 10000,
      noAutoHide: true 
    }
    this.$bvToast.toast('Success', errorToaster)   <<<it's cause a problem because I put it in Modal component?>>>